# Pages that show up in Google search results are not listed as indexed in Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, bing-webmaster-tools

I have a domain `example.com`. I use `www.example.com` as my main. I verified example.com at GSC as a domain property. At GSC only 2 pages are listed:

- `www.example.com`: not indexed because of "Crawled - currently not indexed"
- `example.com`: not indexed because of "Page with redirect"

But my site has other pages:

- `subdomain.example.com/page1`
- `www.example.com/page2`
- etc.

They are indexed according to URL Inspection tool and I can find them on Google.

Why are these pages not shown in my GSC account? As far as I understand, if I have "domain" property I don't need to do anything to include `subdomain.example.com/page1` and `www.example.com/page2` on my GSC.

This is my main question. But I also have a problem with Bing Webmaster - it shows no pages (I imported the site from GSC). I think these problems are related. If I try to use their URL Inspection tool on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), it shows the following error:

We were not able to connect to the DNS (Domain Name Server) for this URL. Please review with your technical team, web hosting company and contact Bing Webmaster support if you are not able to fix the issue.

Comment: How long has your site been up?  How long has it been since you verified the domain property with GSC?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller 5 days. (Sorry for the long reply; I thought I would be notified about new comments and answers by email)

Comment: In general you need to wait 2 weeks for Google Search Console to reflect any changes you make to your site.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the question. I understand why it is so. On the ‘Pages’ section of GSC, it is written ‘Last updated: 2/13/24’. Therefore, this list of indexed pages has not been updated yet, although the pages are, in fact, indexed

Answer (score -1):

There are several issues here, so this is an incomplete answer.

- It appears your site is new.  It can take months to get anything indexed, let alone all pages
- Bing and Yandex are more particular.  Ask Bing Webmaster for help.
- Subdomains are separate sites and have to be verified on their own.
- It is not enough just to show domain ownership, you also need to have some or all of the following.  Every little bit helps.

  - internal links to that page
  - consistency between title, h1 and content
  - you can use a sitemap to submit all the pages
  - or you can submit each page by itself.
  - error-free html and css

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct.  Subdomains are part of domain verified properties: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/10431861?hl=en   You only need to add them separately when you use prefix properties.

Comment: It also looks like you are answering "why are my pages not indexed" rather than "Why are my pages that show up in Google searches not listed as indexed in search console."